# Rails chart.js data coffee script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, dynamic, chart.js

I am new to rails. I want to populate a chart.js chart with data from my database table. I managed to set up the chart with static data.

I need to replace the static data with data from my table sales. sales.month should represent the x-axis and sales.amount should represent the y-axis value.

My app.js.coffee looks like this:

```
sales = sale.select(month, SUM(amount) as sum_of_amount)
months = sales.collect(month)
amts = sales.collect(sum_of_amount)

jQuery ->

  data = {
    labels : months,
    datasets : [
      {
        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : amts
      }
    ]
  }
```

My index.html.haml looks like this and the chart is displayed with the static vaulues.

```
%canvas#canvas{:height => "400", :width => "600"}
```

How do i proceed from here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that there was no data passed into the coffeescript.

I managed getting this done using the gem 'gon'. Here is what i did:

My app.js.coffee file looks like this:

```
jQuery ->
months = $.map( gon.sales, ( val, i ) -> 
            val.month
          );
amts = $.map( gon.sales, ( val, i ) -> 
            val.amount
          );

data = {
  labels : months,
  datasets : [
    {
      fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
      strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
      data : amts
    }
  ]
}
```

In my sales_controller.rb i've added the following:

```
def index
  @sales = Sale.all
  gon.sales = @sales
end
```

In my application.html.haml layout file:

```
= include_gon
```

And ofcourse in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'gon'
```

Finally in index.html.haml:

```
%canvas#canvas{:height => "400", :width => "600"}
```

And now the chart in dynamically populated with data from my sales table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch sum of amount by grouping on `created_at`'s month.

```
orders = Order.select("DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) as month, SUM(amount) as sum_of_amount").group("month")
months = orders.collect(&:month)
amts = orders.collect(&:sum_of_amount)
```

Now you just need to pass `months` in `labels:` and `amts` in `data:`.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Raj, thanks. But i am not there yet. The Chart is not displayed anymore when i use this code:

Comment: `sales = sale.select(month, SUM(amount) as sum_of_amount)
months = orders.collect(month)
amts = orders.collect(sum_of_amount)

jQuery ->

  data = {
    labels : months,
    datasets : [
      {
        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : amts
      }
    ]
  }

  myNewChart = new Chart($("#canvas").get(0).getContext("2d")).Line(data)`

Comment: Can you please add this code in your original post in a formatted way?

Comment: Show me the final values of `months` and `amts` that you are passing

Comment: Sorry but i am new to to rails and coffeescript, but how can i print that output?

Comment: ok, thanks. debugging show data for @sales, but months and amts seem empty.

Comment: we are almost there, any ideas?

Comment: As I said, you need to tweak your queries as shown in original answer. Show me value of `sales`. `months = sales.collect(&:month);
amts = sales.collect(&:sum_of_amount)`

Comment: I thinks the problem is that there is no data passed into the coffeescript. not sure how to accomplish that..